# General solution to a 4th order ODE: $y^{(4)}-k^4 y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How is $y=a \cos kx + b \sin kx + c \cosh kx + d \sinh kx$ the general solution of the ODE?

$$y^{(4)}-k^4 y=0$$

I can not understand how exp e transforms into sin and cos Cosh Sinh

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @VictorTelloDiaz **Hint:** The roots are given by $m^4 - k^4 = 0 \implies m_{1,2,3,4} = \pm ~ k, \pm ik$. Do you see how the exponentials can be written as $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ terms? The $\cos$ and $\sin$ terms are obvious. Please make sure my edits are correct.

Comment: I can not understand How exp e transforms into sin and cos Cosh Sinh

Comment: You should have a look at [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) and consult the defintions of the hyperbolic functions to see the analogy for "real roots" $\pm k$.  If this is not in your skill set, start by taking derivatives and verifying the "general solution" really is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the characteristic equation here is obtained by using the ansatz $y=e^{\lambda x}$. Thus, if you substitute it into the ODE, you will obtain:
$$\lambda^4 e^{\lambda x}-k^4 e^{\lambda x}=0$$
$$e^{\lambda x}(\lambda^4-k^4)=0$$
Since $e^{\lambda x}\neq 0$ for all $\lambda, x\in \mathbb{R}$, we can reduce this to the characteristic equation:
$$\lambda^4-k^4=0$$
The roots to this are obviously $\lambda=\pm k, \pm ik$, as mentioned by @Moo. Hence, the general solution can be written as:
$$y(x)=c_1 e^{kx}+c_2 e^{-kx}+c_3 e^{ikx}+c_4 e^{-ikx} \tag{1}$$

---

You said that you didn't understand how the exponential transforms into the trigonometric and hyperbolic trigonometric functions:

Remember that the **constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$ and $c_4$ are arbitrary**. What do I mean by this? We can *rewrite* this general solution by remembering that $\cosh(x)\equiv \dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\sinh(x)\equiv \dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$. Notice that you can therefore write:
$$A\cosh(kx)=\frac{A}{2}e^{kx}+\frac{A}{2}e^{-kx} \qquad B\sinh(kx)=\frac{B}{2}e^{kx}-\frac{B}{2}e^{-kx}$$
If we add them together, we obtain:
$$\begin{align} A\cosh(kx)+B\sinh(kx)&=\left(\frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}\right)e^{kx}+\left(\frac{A}{2}-\frac{B}{2}\right)e^{-kx}\\&=c_1e^{kx}+c_2e^{-kx} \end{align}$$
Since the constants are arbitrary, we can define $c_1:=\frac{A+B}{2}$ and $c_2:=\frac{A-B}{2}$ as done above, and then substitute it into $(1)$. The first part is complete.

---

Can you do the part with $\cos$ and $\sin$ for $c_3 e^{ikx}+c_4 e^{-ikx}$? Again, remember that constants are arbitrary.

**Hint:** [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)
$$e^{i\theta}\equiv \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$
And remember that $\cos(\theta)$ is even and $\sin(\theta)$ is odd.